# function is everywhere discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ is  a  Dirichlet function
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}f(x)&=1\ x\in \mathbb{Q}\\&=0\ x\notin \mathbb{R-Q}\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

The definition of continuous at x
$f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if for every $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

It is given the function is discontinuous everywhere.

My doubt is, suppose I take any $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ then whenever $x_0\in \mathbb{Q}$, irrespective of size of $\delta$, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0$, so less than any $\epsilon>0$, so can't we say it is continuous at every rational numbers.

Similarly it can be shown continuous at very irrational  number...

I know I am doing something wrong.. But please let me know where i am going wrong with the definition...

Thnaks in advance!!

Comment: $|x-x_0|<\delta$ should give $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ whether or not $x$ is rational.

Comment: As written , this is self-contradicting since a number which is not element of $\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ ,is in $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $f$ is continuous at some rational $x_0$. Hence $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta >0, \,s.t. \, \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \, with |x-x_0|<\delta, |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

In particular, it is true for $\epsilon=1$. Therefore there exists $\delta'$ such that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta', |f(x) -f(x_0) |<1$. Since $x_0$ is rational, $f(x_0)=0$. By density of irrationals, there exists some irrational $y_0$ such that $|y_0 -x_0|<\delta'$. Also, $f(y_0)=1$. But since $f$ is continuous at $x_0, |f(y_0)|<1$ ie) $1<1$ which is absurd. Hence $f$ is not continuous at any rational. Similar argument holds for irrationals.

You missed the point that every interval has both rational and irrational and we need to check for every point in the $\delta$ ball taken.

Answer (score 0):

I hate using natural language for mathematical properties because mathematical language is far more precise. The definition of continuity for a function defined on a set E is:

$$\forall\epsilon \gt 0, \exists\delta\gt0\space/\space\forall x\in E, \left|x-x_0\right|\lt\delta \implies \left|f(x)-f(f_0)\right|\gt\epsilon$$

The part you missed is $\forall x\in E$. As both rationals and irrationals are dense subsets of $\mathbb R$, you will find values of $0$ and $1$ in any interval, hence the function is not continue.

But if you reduce the domain set to $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb {R \setminus Q}$ then the function is a constant on its domain set:

$$\begin{aligned}f: &\mathbb Q \to\mathbb Q\\&x\mapsto1\end{aligned}$$

is of course a continous function on $\mathbb Q$!